# How to integrate Play Framework 2.2.1 with Maven

Tags: java, maven, playframework

I have just started playing with Play Framework for my new project and I am able to write and run an hello world application using Java.

Now I am asked to integrate Maven with this hello world application, but could not find any concrete examples on the web so far. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you need `Maven`? `Maven` is used for `Build- and Dependency-Management`, which is already integrated in the `Play Framework`. (if you really need `Maven`, there's a [module](https://www.playframework.com/modules/maven-1.0/home) for it. With that module Maven will take care of the dependency part.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to download and install [apache maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

finally, you need to install the play-maven module

`play install maven`

https://www.playframework.com/modules/maven-1.0/home

Answer (score 0):

Tried 'play install maven' but it's not working as saying 'invalid symbol'. It seems this cmd works only with play 1.X versions and not works with version 2.X (I'm using 2.2.1 version)

However, I just tried adding following repository and dependency which seems working fine.

```
    <repository>
        <id>typesafe</id>
        <name>Typesafe - releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-java_${play2-scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${play2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need i.e Play2 maven plugin

http://code.google.com/p/play2-maven-plugin/ . At the bottom of the page there is link for working examples .